# Using a SliverFillRemaining with a CustomScrollView and SliverList

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a scrolling list that can have a footer at the bottom of the scrolling list. If the list does not fill up all of the vertical screen space, the footer will need to shift down to the bottom of the page.

I tried implementing this with a `SliverList` and `SliverFillRemaining` in a `CustomScrollView` but the `SliverFillRemaining` shows some unexpected behavior I believe. It fills up more space than needed (see gif).

I used the following piece of code to create this list:

```
child: new CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    new SliverList(
      delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Card(
            child: new Container(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: new Center(child: new Text("Card $index")),
            ),
          );
        },
        childCount: 3,
      ),
    ),
    new SliverPadding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    ),
    new SliverFillRemaining(
      child: new Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

[image: Image showing what is wrong with the listview]

Comment: From the documentation for SliverFillRemaining -  "A sliver that contains a single box child that fills the remaining space in the viewport" and "there is never any room for anything beyond this sliver."  This seems totally expected.

Comment: @JonahWilliams There is no other widgets after this `SliverFillRemaining` though. Also, I think I misunderstood "A sliver that contains a single box child that fills the remaining space in the viewport". Could you clarify?

Comment: I had the same problem. Having a `SliverList` followed by a `SliverFillRemaining` containing a small widget in a `CustomScrollView`, I expected scroll view not to scroll, because all content fitted on the screen. I noticed that the `hasScrollBody` parameter to the `SliverFillRemaining` is `true` by default but my content doesn't scroll. So I switched it to `false` which fixed my issue. Didn't dig deeper.

Comment: Thanks @t.animal. works me.

Comment: Thanks. I encounter the same problem and cant find any solution. Finally come to this post and got the answer. Thanks all

Comment: I still can't figure out why this `hasScrollBody` parameter is ever can be set to true. In all examples it is set to `false`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SliverFillRemaining` will automatically size itself to fill the space between the bottom of the last list item and the bottom of the viewport. See the `performLayout` method of `SliverFillRemaining` for the code:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/sliver_fill.dart#L118

I don't think you can use it to achieve the effect you're going for, though you might be able to create a subclass that would work.

Answer (score 31):

For anyone that is looking for an answer to this, I have a solution that has been working well whenever I needed something similar.

This is how I've managed it:

```dart
class ScrollOrFitBottom extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget scrollableContent;
  final Widget bottomContent;

  ScrollOrFitBottom({this.scrollableContent, this.bottomContent});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverFillRemaining(
          hasScrollBody: false,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: scrollableContent),
              bottomContent
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

As the name says, it will scroll if there is too much content, or have something pushed to the bottom otherwise.

I think it is simple and self-explanatory, but let me know if you have any questions

Example: https://codepen.io/lazarohcm/pen/xxdWJxb

Comment: For me `hasScrollBody: false` did the trick. I can now use `Spacer()` inside a `Column`.

Comment: I got stuck with this problem and I finally found the solution. Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're genius! Thank you for taking time to post this answer you saved many hours of our lives for us!

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Working with expandable UIs inside scrollviews is quite tricky.

Answer (score 3):

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('SliverFillRemaining')),
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverFillRemaining(
        hasScrollBody: false,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            FlutterLogo(size: 200),
            Text(
              'This is some longest text that should be centered'
              'together with the logo',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

[This Package](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_fill_remaining_box_adapter) does exactly what you are expecting, I've been trying for days now,and finally used this, Its works the same way as the SliverToBoxAdapter but extends enough and does not cause over scroll

```
    child: new CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    new SliverList(
      delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Card(
            child: new Container(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: new Center(child: new Text("Card $index")),
            ),
          );
        },
        childCount: 3,
      ),
    ),
    new SliverPadding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    ),
    new SliverFillRemainingBoxAdapter(
      child: new Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Answer (score -4):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55563627/312778) and a Gist file [here](https://gist.github.com/evelyne24/8283cad049b168845f8ea0c553677c65). It may lead you in the right direction.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: constraints.copyWith(
            minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
            maxHeight: double.infinity,
          ),
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(height: 200, color: Colors.blue),
                Container(height: 200, color: Colors.orange),
                Container(height: 200, color: Colors.green),
                Container(height: 50, color: Colors.pink),
                Expanded(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: Text('FOOTER', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: If you have a particular question that you would like me to answer from the code above, please be clear. Otherwise, it's unreasonable to expect explanation line by line. As I mentioned above, this is just an example. In fact, this particular topic is a very difficult one to achieve in Flutter. If you are interested, there are several discussions on Flutter about why is that. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38641 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38640 for your reference.