# Flutter trying to make footer scrollable with content when the screen size is small

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to achieve the exact behavior like below link in **Flutter**:

https://jsfiddle.net/6vzcosyj/

html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
I am content<br>
I am content<br>I am content<br>I am content<br>I am content<br>
I am content<br>
I am content<br>I am content<br>I am content<br>I am content<br>
</div>
<div class="footer">
I am footer
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
}

.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

In above link, if there is space, then content will always try to expand it self, and the footer is always in the bottom. But if there is not enough space, the content and footer can be **scroll** and the footer will no longer stick at the bottom.

You can try to adjust the size of the window in the above link to get what I want to achieve.

I cannot make this behavior in **Flutter**, so any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68572964/13774019

```
class ScrollOrFitBottom extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget scrollableContent;
  final Widget bottomContent;

  ScrollOrFitBottom({this.scrollableContent, this.bottomContent});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverFillRemaining(
          hasScrollBody: false,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: scrollableContent),
              bottomContent
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it in Flutter :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        
class Html extends StatefulWidget {
  const Html({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Html> createState() => _HtmlState();
}

class _HtmlState extends State<Html> {

  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Html',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 42,
            color: Colors.white,),
        ),
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) {
                return const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 7, horizontal: 30),
                  child: Text('I am content'),
                );
              },
              childCount: 10,
            ),
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children:[
                const Text('I am Footer'),
                SizedBox(width: width,),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried and it has a interesting effect. But unfortunately it is not what I want. In your code, the content can be scroll even there are enough space to show both content and footer. But what I want is, if there is enough space, no scrolling. footer keep in bottom. It can be scroll only when there is not enough space to show both content and footer.

Comment: anyway, thanks for your keyword (CustomScrollView, SliverFillRemaining) so that I finally found a solution for what i want. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Column(
      children: [
        Text('data'),
        Text('data'),
        Text('data'),
        Text('data'),
        Text('data'),
              ],
                ),
     Column(
       children: [
         Text('Iam the Footer'),
                 ],
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: sorry I am asking how to do the same effect in Flutter. but not asking how to do it in html. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I also want it can be scroll if the window size is too small. Seems your updated answer cannot be scroll. Thanks